# How to open kcrash files and/or launch drkonqi manually?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, files, bug-reporting, kdenlive

So I was playing with `kdenlive` and it crashed (I didn't add PPA and 11.04 repos has outdated version. It was fixed for 11.10 though). "`DrKonqi`" [as always] said that there is not enough useful information (How do I suppose to check that I've tried to reproduce the bug since it is the first time it happened?). And I saved the report in a `.kcrash` file.
I've reproduced the bug some seconds later, yes. But I closed DrKonqi and wanted to open the first report. And I just couldn't. There is no `drkonqi` package to `dpkg -L` it, there is no such executable in the PATH, .kcrash files is not recognized nor in the `nautilus` neither in the `dolphin`.

Comment: $ locate drkonqi | grep exec
/usr/lib/kde4/libexec/drkonqi

Comment: But still there is no such option for `/usr/lib/kde4/libexec/drkonqi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bugs and reports**

The KDE has a good debugging page /1/. It has useful information how to make useful crash reports:

- "many distros choose to install stripped files, which results in useless backtraces".."If your distribution has debugging-enabled packages, install them."
- The Ubuntu family makes things quite easy. Every official KDE module has an additional package in the repository, suffixed with -dbg. Always install kdelibs5-dbg, because all KDE applications use kdelibs...
- etc...

The Kubuntu wiki has a bug section /2/.

**The kcrash files**

The kcrash files should be text files. At here:

The file command /3/ is telling:

:~$ file /home/rog131/Documents/dolphin-20111014-113228.kcrash
/home/rog131/Documents/dolphin-20111014-113228.kcrash: ASCII text

and/or the mimetype command /4/ is telling:

:~$ mimetype /home/rog131/Documents/dolphin-20111014-113228.kcrash
/home/rog131/Documents/dolphin-20111014-113228.kcrash: text/plain

Here the dedicated text editor is opening the kcrash file when left clicking the file in the file manager.

**DrKonqi**

The drkonqi should start automatically when there is a KDE related crash. You could see the options with the command:

:~$ /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/drkonqi --help

Links & notes:

1. https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Debugging/How_to_create_useful_crash_reports
2. https://wiki.kubuntu.org/Kubuntu/Bugs/Reporting
3. :~$ man file:

NAME
     file — determine file type

4. :~$ man mimetype

NAME
       mimetype - Determine file type